# Simple question on Kirby move

Tags: knot-theory, 3-manifolds, kirby-calculus

From hyperbolic volume computation, I found that the following two 3-manifolds are (possibly orientation-reversal) homeomorphic:

1. surgery on figure-eight knot $4_1$, with slope $-5$, and
2. surgery on $5_2$ knot with slope $5$.

Is there simple way to show it using Kirby calculus?
It must be easy but I am not that familiar with Kirby calculus.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way. Below is a sequence of pictures illustrating the procedure (created using [Kirby calculator](http://community.middlebury.edu/~mathanimations/kirbycalculator/)).

$5_2$: [image: This is $5_2$]
Blowup at the clasp: [image: This is the blowup]
Isotopy: [image: After the isotopy]
Blowdown the purple unknot: [image: And this is after blowing down the purple curve]

Comment: I couldn't follow the isotopy passage. Is it possible to explain it?

Comment: I'm just claiming that the two links (above and below "Isotopy:") differ by a link isotopy in $S^3$. Just undo the kinks of the purple component (i.e. do Reidemeister 1 moves) dragging the golden component along.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your question. Replacing a $\pm1$-framed unknot with a full $\mp1$-twist is always a Kirby move (in the sense that it preserves the boundary, not the 4-manifold it represents). There is no relationship with being alternating here.